# C code example to write to a text file using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, file, pthreads, fopen

I would like to dump some variables every second to a file locally.
My current code structure is the following:

```
pthread_create(hdl, &attr, threadEntry, arg);
```

On my threadEntry function, i have the following

```
FILE *fp;

void threadEntry(void){
    while(1){
        fopen("/directory/here", a);
        fprintf(fp, "Log information here");
        fclose(fp);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to structure my code?
I want the I/O to be away from my main thread, I want it to dump my information to a file every second, and need to run for the life of the program.
Thank you

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to open the file and close it again for every message you want to write.  Open once, write as many times as you want, optionally *flushing* after each write, and close when you're done.  Moreover, your thread function has the wrong signature -- it must accept one argument of type `void *` and return `void *` (or at least be declared that way).

Comment: Should i keep the file open all the time?  If so, would I be able to open the text file outside of the program with no problems?  If i wanted to see the contents of the file

Comment: "see the contents of the file" doesn't mean you'll be writing to it. It means you'll be *reading* it.

Comment: I want to write from the program, but read the output from the file.  Sorry I didn't explain that!

Comment: pthreads is a POSIX technology (that's what the "P" is for).  POSIX systems permit the same file to be open multiple times concurrently by the same or different processes.

Comment: So, should I move the fopen after the FILE* fp and the fclose outside of the while loop?

Comment: As written, your while loop is an infinite loop, so moving the `fclose` out of that would cause the file to never be closed...  (I'm assuming your _real_ code has a method of terminating the loop...).

Comment: So, should i create a signal_thread to handle the closing of the file in case of termination? 
Would the code be fine, if I never close (close fp) it as long as the program is running?
How would you write a thread that constantly write to a file?  Something super basic, you know

Comment: What I usually do is queue write objects/structs/pointer/whatever to the write thread on a producer-consumer queue.  The write thread waits on the queue with a timeout and, if the timeout fires with the file open and with unflushed and writes, (boolean flag), it closes and reopens, (so flushing any outstanding data).  The write thread can run for the app lifetime, and there may be no need to terminate it in any explicit way at all, (which is always good news).

Comment: ...and if you do need that last little bit of data to be flushed, queue up a struct/object that instructs the thread to close the file and exit() the app.  Any outstanding writes would get done first, the file closed and the app would then terminate.